# Open CSS modal box from link in SVG document

Tags: css, hyperlink, svg

I want to implement a modal box according to http://www.paulrhayes.com/2011-03/css-modal/ to open when clicking on a element in a SVG document.

Here's an example code:

```
<svg ...>
<g id="ra">
    <a xlink:href="#r1" class="openModal">
        <g id="r">
            <rect x="136.63" y="98.893" fill="#000000" width="58.79" height="91.313"/>
        </g>
    </a>
</g>
</svg>
<aside id="r1" class="modal">
    <div>
        <h2>Modal box</h2>
            <p>Lorem Ipsum</p>
            <a href="#close" title="Close">Close</a>
    </div>
</aside>
```

Well, as you might guess. This code is not working. Perhaps you can help?
Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Did you just forget to include the css? It works for me once you do that.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://www.paulrhayes.com/experiments/modal/css/experiment.css"/>
        <svg>

        <a xlink:href="#r1" class="openModal">
            <g id="r">
                <rect x="136.63" y="98.893" fill="#000000" width="58.79" height="91.313"/>
            </g>
        </a>
    </g>
    </svg>
    <aside id="r1" class="modal">
        <div>
            <h2>Modal box</h2>
                <p>Lorem Ipsum</p>
                <a href="#close" title="Close">Close</a>
        </div>
    </aside>
    </html>
```

Comment: Ah, no. I have the css included. But I just saw, that it's just not working in Chrome. Safari works perfect. So, now the question is, how to make this cross-browser.